# jQuery - .css('transform') returning different values in Internet Explorer than Chrome/Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, matrix, gsap

As a bit of background, I'm using Greensock's [Draggable](https://greensock.com/draggable) to move an object on the y-axis with the `transform:translate3d` property.

However, when I call for a return on the moving object with `.css('transform')`, the values returned in IE are different than what Chrome/Firefox are returning.

For example, Chrome/Firefox return `matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 5)` while IE returns `matrix3d(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 5, 0, 1)`.

I need to parse and grab the changing y-value, which is position [5] within Chrome/Firefox and position [13] within IE. This is obviously proving to be an issue without implementing some browser sniffing.

Is there a way for me to either standardize the property value that is returned (either to matrix or matrix3d), or maybe grab the y-value on its own in a different way?

**Edit:** Not sure why my question received a negative rating; if I'm not providing enough information, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else ever has this issue and is using Greensock (GSAP), I was supplied with the following answer over at the [Greensock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16444-draggable-csstransform-returning-different-values-in-ie-than-chromefirefox/#entry72489):

> If you're trying to figure out the y position of the Draggable's
>   target, did you know that the Draggable instance has a "y" property as
>   well? So you could just tap into that.
>
> Example:
>
> ```
> Draggable.create("#id", {
>     onDrag:function() {
>         console.log(this.y);
>     }
> });
> ```

Another answer suggested that the different values could be the result of a bug within jQuery's .css('transform').

Either way, this solved my issue.

Answer (score -1):

Find this from Microsoft, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj200269(v=vs.85).aspx.

> All other transformation functions are based on the matrix3d function.

You can extract the value you need. Looks like that is the only option.

[image]